# Infix to postfix C program

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I've been making a program to convert infix input to postfix with the help of stack.
The program I've made is as follows

This runs as an infinite loop without printing anything relevant. I've been trying to find the error but haven't been successful, The compiler also did not issue any warnings.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char po[20];
int top = -1;

void push(char x) {
  po[++top] = x;
}

char pop() {
  if (top == -1)
    return -1;
  else
    return po[top--];
}

int priority(char x) {
  if (x == '(')
    return 0;
  if (x == '+' || x == '-')
    return 1;
  if (x == '*' || x == '/')
    return 2;
}

main() {
  char st[20], x;
  int a, c = 0, op;
  printf("Enter the expression ");
  scanf("%s", st);
  while (st[c] != '\0') {
    if (st[c] >= 'a' && st[c] <= 'z')
      printf("%c", st[c]);
    else if (st[c] == '(')
      push(st[c]);
    else if (st[c] == ')')
      ;
    {
      while ((x = pop()) != '(')
        printf("%c", pop());
    }
    if (st[c] == '*' || st[c] == '/' || st[c] == '+' || st[c] == '-'
        || st[c] == '^') {
      while (priority(po[top]) >= priority(st[c]))
        printf("%c", pop());
      push(st[c]);
    }
    c = c + 1
  }
  while (top != -1) {
    printf("%c", pop());
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not appear to modify `c` anywhere in your `while(st[c]!='\0')` loop.  That would explain it.

Comment: Still getting the same infinite loop issue, Removed it by mistake

Comment: `main()` has no return type?

Comment: what do `a` and `op` do in your code?

Comment: what happens in `priority()` when `x` is not a `(` nor `+` nor `*`.

Comment: The trailing `;` on `else if(st[c]==')');` is surely erroneous.  Your program seems to work on some simple cases when I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

> The compiler also did not issue any warnings.

Save time.  Enable all warnings or get a better compiler.

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Review below function and see that it does not return a value for all possible `x`.

```
int priority(char x) {
  if (x == '(')
    return 0;
  if (x == '+' || x == '-')
    return 1;
  if (x == '*' || x == '/')
    return 2;

  // Missing return
}
```

---

```
warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
```

The below code is suspicious.  Do you really want a `;` after `else if (st[c] == ')')`?

```
else if (st[c] == ')')
  ;
```

---

```
error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

Certainly a typo (missing ;)

```
// c = c + 1
c = c + 1;
```

---

Other problems may exist too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the code that does not give an infinite loop at least.

Changes to Note:

1. Always use `{ }` with your `if` blocks and your loop blocks.
2. In this bit of code, in addition to the unnecessary `;`, which others have pointed out, you were popping twice! which is not what you want. If you pop in the `printf()`, this `while` loop will never terminate, since it will never see the `(`.

   ```
   else if(st[c]==')') {
           while((x=pop()) != '(') {
              printf("%c",pop());
           }
       }
   ```

   Here is how the fixed code looks like:

   ```
   else if(st[c]==')') {
           while((x=pop()) != '(') {
              printf("%c",x);
           }
       }
   ```

Finally always have a default `return` from your function.

- There could still be other logical errors in your code. It just does not give an infinite loop now.

## Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char po[20];
int top = -1;

void push(char x)
{
    po[++top] = x;
}
char pop()
{
    if(top==-1)
        return -1;
    else
        return po[top--];
}

int priority(char x)
{
    if(x == '(')
        return 0;
    if(x == '+' || x == '-')
        return 1;
    if(x == '*' || x == '/')
        return 2;
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char st[20],x;
    int a,c=0,op;
    printf("Enter the expression ");
    scanf("%s",st);
    while(st[c]!='\0')
    {
        if(st[c]>='a'&& st[c]<='z') {
            printf("%c",st[c]);
        }
        else if(st[c]=='(') {
            push(st[c]);
        }
        else if(st[c]==')') {
            while((x=pop()) != '(') {

                printf("%c",x);
            }
        }


        if(st[c]=='*' || st[c]=='/' || st[c]=='+' || st[c]=='-' || st[c]=='^')
        {
            while(priority(po[top])>priority(st[c])) {

                printf("%c",pop());
            }
            push(st[c]);
        }


        c=c+1;
    }
    while(top!=-1)
    {


        printf("%c",pop());
    }
}
```

## Output:

Here is how the output looks like:

> junglefox@ubuntu:~/test_programs/$
>
> ./test Enter the expression (2+3)*4/5*2*3-4/(5+4)
>
> +**/*+/-junglefox@ubuntu:~/test_programs/$

Comment: Also make that buffer bigger. I didnt realize but with my test expression, i managed to have a buffer overrun.